# JavaScript Scope: timer referencing arbitrary new object

Tags: javascript, scope

Here is the code for what I am basically trying to do:

```
document.body.addEventListener("keypress", f1, false);

function f1(e){
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    window.setInterval(function(){
        ...
            window.clearInterval(this);
            document.body.removeChild(span);
}
```

So in short, I'm trying to make a new DOM element, and then attach a timer to it that will be able to reference that particular object.  The problem is, I don't know how to do the context, so `this` just references `window`, and JavaScript throws an error when I try to reference `span` (which I wasn't expecting to work anyway).  How can I set the context of the interval to the DOM element I created in that function?

Comment: I think you want `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`...

Comment: Accessing `span` should not throw an error. It's still part of the local scope.

Comment: Fun fact: `clearInterval` can be used to clear timeouts, too...

Comment: Accessing `span` doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't work properly either - all the elements are still there on the page.  And I'm sorry if it's confusing, but I do want setInterval, the interval is cleared as part of an else statement (I removed all the control to simplify the question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setInterval` returns an integer which is the id of the timer. So, all you have to do is to store it:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
// ...
    clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to access the object, I'm not having problems clearing the interval.

Comment: Yes, you're having that problem. You're using an interval, so that's what I think it happens here: 1) the interval function is executed; 2) `clearInterval` fails to clear the interval; 3) the `<span>` is removed from the DOM; 4) after a while, the interval function _is executed again_; 5) `clearInterval` fails again; 6) Trying to remove the `<span>` raises an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Keep a variable for your interval:

```
document.body.addEventListener("keypress", f1, false);

function f1(e){
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
        ...
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            document.body.removeChild(span);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to access the object, I'm not having problems clearing the interval.